# Writing Bits across two bytes

Tags: c, dataframe, embedded, can-bus

I have a requirement where I have to write a HEX value to an 11 bit "container" across two bytes. The layout is as follows: Byte 5(bit 3) is the lsb and data goes to Byte 4(bit 5)which is the msb. What is the best method for writing data to the bit locations in question.

For example if I need to write the value 0x1DA to these locations what would be the best way of doing that while keeping the bit ordering correct.

FYI the is for CAN communication for an 8 byte CAN message.

I was thinking of doing this:

```
_templsb = DatatoWrite & 0x1F;
_templsb <<= 3;
Byte5 &= ~0xF8;
Byte5 = Byte5 | _templsb;

_tempmsb = DatatoWrite & 0x7E0;
_tempmsb >>= 5;
Byte4 &= ~0x3F;
Byte4 =  Byte4 | _tempmsb;
```

Is something like this the best way to do it?

Comment: Not enough info.  Please provide a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.

Comment: The best method? One method is shifting, ANDing and ORring.

Comment: I added to my comment on what I was thinking of doing. Please let me know if I am way off base or not.

Comment: Well you definitely don't want to be using `&&` and `||` as those are the logical operators rather than bit-wise operators.

Comment: Do you know that the existing bits are 0 before adding the new bits?  If not, then you need to clear them.

Comment: Sorry about that I meant to || Byte 5 with _templsb not &&

Comment: As you can see I am a newb replace && with & and || with |

Comment: I added bit clearing to the bytes before writing the bits. Please let me know if you see any errors in my logic.

Comment: 11 bit "container" across two bytes. The layout is as follows: Byte 5(bit 3)"  What byte 5 of what? Byte 5 out of 2? I don't understand what you are asking. Maybe if you post the CAN message register layout from the CAN controller manual? Also, endianess might matter so tell us which CPU/CAN controller this is.

Comment: It is often better post a clear question and omit your own suggestions - that is like answering your own question - which you can do, but separately as an answer.  That way you get answers to your problem rather then a critique of your solution.  The question lacks clarity.  What for example should happen to the bits not occupied by the 11 bits of data in question?  Do they contain data already, or can they be zero , one or don't care?

Comment: Since this is split across bytes, beware of any sort of Atomic issues when needing to access.  Especially if this is being written on to memory mapped I/O or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, it appears that the following arrangement is what you wish to achieve:

[image]

So that for your example 0x01DA, the transform would be:

[image]

- Byte4 = 0x0E
- Byte5 = 0xD0

That being the case, then:

```
uint16_t Word = 0x1DA ;
uint8_t Byte4 = (Word & 0x07E0) >> 5 ;
uint8_t Byte5 = (Word & 0x001F) << 3 ;
```

If the unused bits in `Byte4` and `Byte5` already contain data that must remain unchanged, then:

```
Byte4 = (Byte4 & 0xC0) | (Word & 0x07E0) >> 5 ;
Byte5 = (Byte5 & 0x07) | (Word & 0x001F) << 3 ;
```